# What to do with operators with the same precedence in an unambiguous grammar?

Tags: automata, context-free, formal-grammars

I'm trying to create an unambiguous grammar for a calculator that uses $+$, $-$, $*$, $/$ and $()$.
From watching videos and reading articles online, I understand how to create the grammar with $+$, $*$, $()$ (or 3 different precedences).

i.e. $E \to E + E \mid E * E \mid (E) \;\mid \;\text{num}$

$$\begin{align}
E &\to E + F \mid T\\
T &\to T * F \mid F\\
F &\to(E)\;|\; \text{num}\\
\end{align}$$

How would I include $-$ and $/$ in this? Would this approach be correct (unambiguous)?

$$\begin{align}
E &\to E + F \mid E - F \mid T\\
T &\to T * F \mid T / F \mid F\\
F &\to(E)\;|\; \text{num}\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Unrelated: Does 1+2*3 parse the way you are hoping it will?

Comment: Is the resulting grammar still unambiguous? Does it parse sample input correctly? If so, the approach is correct.